# How to resolve multiple simultaneous ball collisions in a pool game?

Tags: physics, collision-resolution, billiards

I'm trying to simulate a break shot in billiards (1 ball hits a pyramid of 15 balls).
The formula for 2D ball collision works correctly in my game. But when it is applied to the break-shot, the result doesn't look realistic. (Only the 2 balls in the corners of the pyramid move, but the rest stays in place).

The problem is that because 15 balls are touching each other, there is an "infinite" number of simultaneous collisions following the first one.

What algorithm or formula can be used to resolve that?

Comment: The behavior you're observing is what you'd expect with instantaneous force transfer between balls. Other, more realistic models can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/659318/286348).